# how to install apc cache for magento

Tags: magento, caching, apc

I am new in magento and i had created 1 magento website.i want to setup APC cache for my magento website.

My hosting provider installed apc catch in server,i check using php_info().now i want to setup that in my magento website.

I read somany blog and forum but did not get proper solution.

Still i don't nor from where i can start.

Can you please help me and give me 100 % solution for that.

Please please give me proper solution from starting to end.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/speeding-up-magento-with-apc-or-memcached/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set-up APC in magento, you need to install php_apc.dll to your extension directory, and then need to do setting to php.ini files, after then need define in local.xml file for APC calling.

Please follow below few links which will help you.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8937/P0/
http://www.aitoc.com/en/blog/apc_speeds_up_Magento.html

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/speeding-up-magento-with-apc-or-memcached/
http://www.magecorner.com/magento-apc-cache/